# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nbformat'

Tags: python, jupyter, quarto

I would like to run python in a `Quarto` document. I followed the [docs](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/python.html) about installing and using python in Quarto, but the error stays. Here is some reproducible code:

````
---
title: "matplotlib demo"
format:
  html:
    code-fold: true
jupyter: python3
---

For a demonstration of a line plot on a polar axis, see @fig-polar.

```{python}
#| label: fig-polar
#| fig-cap: "A line plot on a polar axis"

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r
fig, ax = plt.subplots(
  subplot_kw = {'projection': 'polar'} 
)
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax.set_rticks([0.5, 1, 1.5, 2])
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```
````

Error output:

```
Starting python3 kernel...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/share/jupyter/jupyter.py", line 21, in <module>
    from notebook import notebook_execute, RestartKernel
  File "/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/share/jupyter/notebook.py", line 16, in <module>
    import nbformat
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nbformat'
```

I also checked with Quarto if Jupyter is installed in the terminal like this:

```
quarto check jupyter
```

Output:

```
[✓] Checking Python 3 installation....OK
      Version: 3.7.11 (Conda)
      Path: /Users/quinten/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python
      Jupyter: 4.12.0
      Kernels: julia-1.8, python3

[✓] Checking Jupyter engine render....OK
```

Which seems to be OK. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this error?

---

**Edit: output conda info --envs**

Output of conda info:

```
# conda environments:
#
                         /Users/quinten/.julia/conda/3
                         /Users/quinten/Library/r-miniconda
                         /Users/quinten/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
                         /Users/quinten/Library/rminiconda/general
                         /Users/quinten/opt/anaconda3
base                  *  /Users/quinten/opt/miniconda3
```

---

**Edit: conda install Jupyter**

The condo install Jupyter was installed (thanks to @shafee), now when I check with quarto if Jupyter exists, I get the following error:

```
quarto check jupyter

[✓] Checking Python 3 installation....OK
      Version: 3.7.11 (Conda)
      Path: /Users/quinten/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python
      Jupyter: 4.11.1
      Kernels: julia-1.8, python3

(/) Checking Jupyter engine render....Unable to load extension: pydevd_plugins.extensions.types.pydevd_plugin_pandas_types
Unable to load extension: pydevd_plugins.extensions.types.pydevd_plugin_pandas_types
[✓] Checking Jupyter engine render....OK
```

Comment: Have you installed the `nbformat` using `pip install` or `conda install` ?

Comment: Hi @shafee, Thank you for your suggestion. I tried both and it says it is already installed, but the error stays, unfortunately.

Comment: And have you created that `r-reticulate` env or it was created by `{reticulate}` package?

Comment: Hm, I think the problem is that, quarto is using the python installed in `r-reticulate` environment but `jupyter` is not installed in `r-reticulate`

Comment: Can you show me the output of `conda info --envs`?

Comment: @shafee,  please check edit above!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error usually occurs when `jupyter` is not installed in the environment that is being used and from the output of `quarto checks`,  its seems that Quarto is referring to the `r-reticulate` environment and possibly `jupyter` is not installed in that environment. If thats the case, you simply need to install `jupyter` in the `r-reticulate` environment.

### Option 01

One option could be to activate the `r-reticulate` environment and then install the `jupyter` there.

So first, activate the environment.

```
conda activate r-reticulate
```

and then install `jupyter` there,

```
conda install jupyter
```

### Option 02

If conda could not find that environment, use the specific path to that environment to install `jupyter` in that environment,

```
/Users/quinten/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python -m pip install jupyter
```

### Option 03

If the `r-reticulate` environment is created by the [`{reticulate}`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/index.html) R package, then an easy option could be using [`reticulate::conda_install`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/conda-tools.html) to install a package.

```
reticulate::conda_install(envname = "r-reticulate", "jupyter")
```

---

Also, if you are wondering, why `jupyter` command runs even though it did not exist in the `r-reticulate` environment, its because you probably installed `jupyter` in the base environment and quarto is detecting that `jupyter` installation while checking.

Comment: Weird, in your updated question, `r-reticulate` is shown in the output of  `conda info --envs`. Ok then, there is another way. See the edit. Does it work?

Comment: It is may be related with [this](https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues/5562) issue. By the way, does this stop the rendering process?

Comment: I restarted Rstudio and now it is fixed, thank you very much @shafee

Comment: I have tried to add more explanation as per my knowledge. : )